# How can i access Ruby/Rails core date class within module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I overload some classes of a module with an initializer script. In the module there is a class called `Date` so it is not possible to use `Date.today` or other date methods. How can i access Ruby/Rails core date class? `Rails::Date` does not work.

Comment: When you say "within module", is this a non-rails application -- basically just in ruby land, not rails?

Comment: Its a rails gem that i extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use "::" before the Date class.

Rails just extends the Ruby Core Date class, so you can just use

```
  ::Date.today
```